# "No work is done by NRF ___ weight." Which conjunction (or/and) appropriate in this context?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions

### The General Question

Which of the following is grammatically correct?

1. > It's not good for him **or** her.
2. > It's not good for him **and** her.

Using `neither..nor` or `either...or` structure is a very safe alternative:

3. > It's good for *neither* A *nor* B.
4. > It's not good for *either* A *or* B.

But sentences 3 and 4 are too stilted for casual day-to-day speaking purposes.

For reasons not obvious to me, sentence 1 sounds more "correct". Maybe because the conjunction **or** is also used in sentences 3 and 4, which are  very familiar structures.

---

### Specific Context-based Question

Which conjuction should I use in this case?

> NRF of 200 N is acting upwards and weight of 200 N is acting
>   downwards. But the object is not moving in either of these two
>   directions. Therefore, no work is done by NRF ___ weight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentences 1 and two are both grammatically correct: you would use sentence 1 if you wanted to talk about the effect on the two people individually, and sentence 2 if you wanted to talk about the effect on them **as a couple**.

As you say, 3 and 4 are somewhat more formal, and also more emphatic.

Note that, unless you particularly want to emphasise the **not**, you would be much more likely to say **it isn't**, rather than **it's not**.

Informally you would probably say

> It isn't good for either of them

Regarding the text that you have added: it's important to be specific as it is explaining a scientific point,  and it's OK to be formal in this context. I therefore think that **either... or** or **neither ... nor** would be appropriate:

> An NRF of 200 N is acting upwards and a weight of 200 N is acting downwards. The object is not moving in either direction, therefore 
>   no work is done by **either** the NRF **or** the weight.
>
> An NRF of 200 N is acting upwards and a weight of 200 N is acting downwards. The object is not moving in either direction, therefore 
>   **neither** the NRF **nor** the weight are doing any work.

Note that indefinite articles are required in the first sentence (because we are describing the two new forces for the first time), and definite articles are required in the second sentence (because we are referring to forces that we have already described).

Comment: Which conjuction should I use in this context?

`NRF of 200 N is acting upwards and weight of 200 N is acting downwards. But the object is not moving in either of these two directions. Therefore, no work is done by NRF ___ weight.`

Comment: @SohaFarhinPine: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

*Neither...nor* is not "too stilted for causal day-to-day speaking purposes". That is an exaggeration.  You could say to a car salesman, for example, after he had presented you with two options:

> Neither the X nor the Y gets good enough gas mileage for me.

Although you might not *begin* the conversation with such as sentence, as that would indeed be somewhat stilted. It would certainly tell the car salesman that you were a "no-nonsense" consumer, not one to be bedazzled by shiny chrome.

Or you could say to a friend

> Neither the red blouse nor the green blouse looked good with that skirt. I liked the blue one best.

if the conversation had progressed something like this:

> Did you like the red blouse?
>   --Not really.
>   How about the green one?
>   --It clashed with the skirt. In fact, neither the red blouse nor the green blouse went very well with that skirt. The blue one looked the best.

You could say, as JavaLatte has suggested, "It isn't good for either of them."
Or you could say "It's good for **neither of them**."